# When analyzing national surveys, do I always weight the answers with the expansion factor to get represenative results?

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, survey, weights, representative

When analyzing national surveys, do I always weigh the answers with the expansion factor to get represenative results?

Alternatively, would it be wrong to just "weigh" each answer with 1 and ignore expansion factors?

The data I have has varying expansion factors for every respondent. I want to perform a descriptive and representative analysis.

[Expansion factors:
With only a small part of the population chosen for a probability survey, each interview is vital because many other elements of the population are represented by that one interview.
The *expansion factors* are used to expand the individual responses up to an estimate for the entire population.  An expansion factor of 293 means that one respondent in the probability survey represents 293 operations in the population.

(Source: https://www.nass.usda.gov/Education_and_Outreach/Understanding_Statistics/Statistical_Aspects_of_Surveys/survey_is_survey.pdf)

Is there a better word for this?]

Comment: Please explain what the "expansion factor" is: this is not standard English terminology.

Comment: And the nature of the analysis - "analysis" could be almost anything

Comment: Re the edit: a standard term is "sampling weight."  Whether you weight your results with these numbers depends on your purpose.  For instance, a statistical *description* might want to ignore the weights in order to focus on the *actual data,* whereas most statistical *estimates* and *hypothesis tests* would have to employ the weights.